# Installed Jar is not picked up in compilation

Tags: maven

I successfully installed a local jar to my repo using this command

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=myjar.jar -DgroupId=com.mygroup -DartifactId=art -Dversion=1.3 -DlocalRepositoryPath=/home/me/.m2/repository -Dpackaging=jar
```

This then created the jar file and pom in my repo correctly, so I can find it under com/mygroup/artifact/1.3/

but when I try to reference it in my project pom using (exactly what is defined in the installed pom)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mygroup</groupId>
        <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
</dependency>
```

I get errors when trying to compile. It fails to find the installed jar.

```
Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.myproject:war:1.0: Failure to find com.mygroup:artifact:jar:1.3 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

Im struggling to understand why it is failing to pick up my installed jar. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try `mvn compile -U` (to force the update)?

Comment: Get similar result

`Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/1.3/xxxx-1.3.pom
[WARNING] The POM for xxxx:xxxx:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/1.3/xxxx-1.3.jar` then after that  `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project xxxx: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.xxxx:war:1.0: Could not find artifact com.xxxx.xxxx:xxxxs:jar:1.3 in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your mvn install:install-file you are publishing an artifactID of "art", and later you talk about it being "artifact".  I assume this is just a typo in the obfuscation you made after running into the error.

It's hard to see what's going on without more details.  I would suggest you blow away your local repo, redeploy the local file, and try again.  Also, don't specify a localRepositoryPath (the default is what you want and this is one more potential source of error).  Make sure you do this as the same user, preferably from the same shell to be sure.

Comment: So after blitz my .m2 and doing install-file without the localRepoPath part that seemed to make everything work. Thanks.

Comment: I dont have enough reputation yet. Ive marked it as the answer, as I get more rep I will go back and update it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I used the below ...

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Autus1\Autus1_Practice\bundle\target\Autus1_Service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.autus1.cq5 -DartifactId=Autus1_Service -Dversion=1.3 -DlocalRepositoryPath=C:\Users\manish_ranjan\.m2\repository -Dpackaging=jar
```

instead of....

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=C:\Autus1\Autus1_Practice\bundle\target\Autus1_Service-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar -DgroupId=com.autus1.cq5 -DartifactId=Autus1_Service -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -DlocalRepositoryPath=C:\Users\manish_ranjan\.m2\repository -Dpackaging=jar
```

and it worked. :)

The only change was version "1.3" instead of "1.0-SNAPSHOT" which gave me the solution and my project2 started recognizing this dependency from my project1

```
 <dependency> 
       <groupId>com.autus1.cq5</groupId> 
       <artifactId>Autus1_Service</artifactId>
       <version>1.3</version>
      <scope>compile</scope> 
 </dependency>
```

Thanks for the clue!

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you found a answer useful you can [vote it up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). Please do not use answers for this purpose.